# NSFetchedResultsController with didChangeObject is slow to show cell in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I use NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to display my cells after all my datas are downloaded and inserted into coreData. 
I use the code below to know when a modification occurred

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshDatas:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

then, this method is called

```
- (void)refreshDatas:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

But, i have a problem, there is 5 to 10 seconds between the first call of insertRowAtIndexPath  of the delegate NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and the display of the cell inserted in the UITableView and i don't know why.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using a background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a background thread and the notification is fired there, you need to "republish" the notification in the main thread like:

```
- (void)refreshDatas:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  if ([notification object] == [self managedObjectContext]) return;

  if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshDatas:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
      return;
  }

  [[self managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

If this it is not the problem, try to add some details to your question. Core Data is difficult and without details it's difficult to understand what is going on.

**Edit**

You don't merge changes if the `[notification object]` (a context in this case) is the main one. On the contrary, if that context is coming from a different thread, you merge changes. This is for performance reasons but you could simply remove it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx you very very much, but I don't understand why you do that : if ([notification object] == [self managedObjectContext]) return;

Comment: @marcL I added an edit. Upvote too if you want. Does the solution work for you?